# keep bootstrap nav-tabs show but active dropdown menu persist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've below code to keep the active tab aftrer refresh, however, the active dropdown menu is persist after the page refresh. How do I hide/toggle the active dropdown menu?

This is the java script code using to keep the active tab after refresh:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
        });
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        if (activeTab) {
            console.log(activeTab);
            $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
```